# How to parse json data into different object dynamically by using Jackson in Spring3 MVC project

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I want to know if there is a way to parse json data dynamically into different object by using jackson feature in Spring3.

I have a parent class as below:

```
public class Recording {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And two children:

```
public class Child1Recording extends Recording {
    private String program;

    public String getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }
}

public class Child2Recording extends Recording {
    private String time;

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/init/postCheck.ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String postCheck(@RequestBody Recording recording) {
    if (recording instanceof Child2Recording) {
        return "\"child2 success\"";
    } else if (recording instanceof Child1ecording) {
        return "\"child1 success\"";
    }
    return "\"only parent Recording\"";
}
```

i have different scenarios to post different json data to the backend, i am wondering if there is a way to make controller works like i said above?

For now, if i send a Child2Recording data, an error occurs when parsing it. I can't get the correct object that i expect.

Comment: Can you edit and put the `@RequestBody` that you are posting?

Comment: Check this link [http://programmerbruce.blogspot.fr/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.fr/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) Mainly the 6th example showing how to deserialize json data into polymorphic java objects based on specific json entries.